# "First business day of first week in each month"?

Tags: dates

I would like to say a day which meet the following criteria for each month:
- First whole week
- First business day

For example, the **day** in Dec 2016 is 5, in Jan 2017 is 3 (assume 2 Jan 2017 is holiday).

Currently I only can think of "First business day of first week in each month", but it's sound little bit clumsy and cannot point out the *first whole week*.

Is there have any better to present this "**day**"?

Thanks

Comment: This seems more like a user interface question, not about learning English. I would say "The first Monday of the month (unless that is a holiday)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for a very specific date calculation.

> First business day of the first whole week of the month

is the best you can do, I think.

You haven't specified week boundaries, however.  If the 1st of the month is a Monday, does that count?  Or do weeks start on Sundays?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to "translate" the date calculation in "description", which used in documentation.  About the week boundaries, it will affect the calculation, but seems not related to the "description" :D

Comment: When in doubt, provide examples.